# How to structure semantally-correct recursive mutable borrow with callback to satisfy borrow checker?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a struct that generates data via callback. Inside the callback, I need to modify the struct, process, then unmodify. At the end of the callback, the struct is semantically unmodified but the code has a recursive mutable borrow which Rust doesn't like.

Here's a reduced [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9e46fa3ae828e2963abbacc096bd3a99):

```rust
struct A(u64);
impl A {
    fn change(&mut self, x: u64) { self.0 ^= x; }
    fn gen_data(&self, mut cb: impl FnMut(u64)) {
        for i in 0..64 { cb(self.0 >> i) }
    }
}

fn compute(a: &mut A) -> u64 {
    let mut acc = 0;
    a.gen_data(|x| {
        a.change(x); // change
        acc ^= a.0;  // accumulate result
        a.change(x); // undo
    });
    acc
}
```

I cannot change `gen_data` to be an iterator due to many conditionals in actual implementation. I don't want to clone `a` because it is a large data structure, and also don't want to accumulate the callback data in a container, then process, due to this being hot code.

It's semantically correct. Any way to restructure this code to convince Rust that it works?

Comment: Have you considered using interior mutability, [like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ee03998c432924abb0c624ba10822288)? It won't win you elegance prizes, but it works fine in situations like this, and the runtime overhead is very small (if there is one).

Comment: Can you refactor the `change` part so that the relevant results of the change are computed functionally without actually changing things?

Answer (score 2):

You can get this to work by making `gen_data` take `&mut self` and adding a `&mut Self` parameter to the `FnMut` and then making the changes through that parameter instead of through `a`:

```rust
struct A(u64);
impl A {
    fn change(&mut self, x: u64) { self.0 ^= x; }
    fn gen_data(&mut self, mut cb: impl FnMut(&mut Self, u64)) {
        for i in 0..64 { cb(self, self.0 >> i) }
    }
}

fn compute(a: &mut A) -> u64 {
    let mut acc = 0;
    a.gen_data(|this, x| { // `this` will be `a` when `cb` is called
        this.change(x); // change
        acc ^= this.0;  // accumulate result
        this.change(x); // undo
    });
    acc
}
```